# ASP.NET - Cross Page Posting From Custom Control

Tags: asp.net, postback, user-controls

Can I get some help posting across different pages from a custom control?
I've created a custom button that raises it's own click event through the following code:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Const EventName As String = "button_click"
    Const ArgName As String = "__EVENTARGUMENT"

    If Page.IsPostBack _
    AndAlso Request.Params IsNot Nothing _
    AndAlso Request.Params(ArgName).Trim = EventName Then
        Me.OnClick(Me.this_button, New EventArgs)
    Else
        Me.this_button.Attributes.Add("OnClick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me.this_button, EventName))
    End If

End Sub
```

How would I go about modifying this to let me post to a different page?

I'd like it to act as close as possible to the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button property PostBackUrl.

Comment: That's why I posted the other option of using the  WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions js method instead of using "Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cross Page Postbacks](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4687/cross-page-postbacks-in-aspnet-20/).

You can also use the [WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions](http://anuraj.wordpress.com/2007/11/02/webform_dopostbackwithoptions/) js method to postback the current page to another page.

Comment: That solution makes use of the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button, which specifically has a property for PostBackUrl.  As stated in the title and text of my question, I am using a custom control which has no such property.  I'm afraid your answer doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks, the second option you gave fit the bill nicely.